# Trying to find the number of chart series collection in powerpoint using vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to find the last series collection index number in the clustered column chart using vba macro.  eg. If I have to find the number of slide

```html
Sub GettingLastSlideNumber()

  With ActivePresentation
    MsgBox .Slides(.Slides.Count).SlideNumber
  End With

End Sub
```

in the similar way, I am trying to find the clustered column charts Last series number.

Could someone please assist me on this.

Comment: see my answer below (if I understood your post - to find the count of series in an Excel Sheet Clustered Column Chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Sub seriescounter()
   Dim osld As Slide
   Dim oshp As Shape
   Set osld = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)      'or whatever index
   For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
      If oshp.HasChart Then
         If oshp.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered Then MsgBox oshp.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
      End If
   Next oshp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of Series collection in a Clustered Column Chart in an Excel sheet, use the code below :

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindLastSeries_inChart()

Dim cht                     As ChartObject
Dim Series_counter          As Integer    

' modify "Sheet 1" Name to your needed Sheet, and "Chart 1" to your chart's name
Set cht = Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1")    

Series_counter = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count

MsgBox "Series count in Chart is " & Series_counter    

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai.  it works in Excel.  I am struggling to find it in Powerpoint charts

Comment: @SivaKumar please mark as answer, if you need anything else, open a new post with your needs